# (Python 3 ATM Program) How do I update the Balance every time I withdraw and Deposit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating python ATM for my project, and I need to Update the Balance every time I withdraw and Deposit. However, when I withdraw then check the balance, the balance does not update. Same thing when I withdraw or deposit. How do I update the Balance every time I withdraw and Deposit?

```
balance=1000
print("    Simple ATM Program   ")
print("\n1)\tBalance\n2)\tWithdraw\n3)\tDeposit\n4)\tQuit\n")
def viewbalance():
    print("Your Current Balance is: ₱", balance)
def withdrawbalance():
    viewbalance()
    withdraw = int(input("Enter Amount to Withdraw: "))
    if withdraw < 1000:
        withdrawal = balance - withdraw
        print("Withdrawal Succeed")
        print("Your Remaining Balance is: ₱" + str(withdrawal))
    else:
        print("Insufficient Balance")
        print("Enter a Valid Balance")
        return withdrawbalance()
def depositbalance():
    viewbalance()
    deposit = float(input("Enter Deposit Amount: ₱ "))
    deposit = balance + deposit
    print("Your New Balance is: ₱" + str(deposit))
while True:
    Option = int(input("Select Option: "))
    if Option == 1:
        viewbalance()
    elif Option == 2:
        withdrawbalance()
    elif Option == 3:
        depositbalance()
    elif Option == 4:
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please Select Only the Options Above")
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use floats for currency calculation, use integer numbers of cents instead. This avoids floating point error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
balance=1000
print("    ATM    ")
print("\n1)\tBalance\n2)\tWithdraw\n3)\tDeposit\n4)\tQuit\n")
while True:
    Option=int(input("Enter Option: "))

    if Option==1:
        print("Balance  $ ",balance)


    if Option==2:
        print("Balance  $  ",balance)
        Withdraw=float(input("Enter Withdraw amount $ "))
        if Withdraw>0 and Withdraw<=balance:
            balance -= Withdraw
            print("Foreward Balance  $ ",balance)
        elif Withdraw>balance:
            print("No funs in account")
        else:
            print("None withdraw made")

    if Option==3:
        print("Balance  $ ",balance)
        Deposit=float(input("Enter deposit amount $ "))
        if Deposit>0:
            balance += Deposit
            print("Forewardbalance  $ ",balance)
        else:
            print("None deposit made")


    if Option==4:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 'forewardbalance' variable with the variable 'balance'

or

Set  the balance variable to foreward balance in your options.

`balance=forewardbalance`

Additional tip: In Option 2, make the elif condition (balance is greater than the withdrawal amount ) as the if condition.